# How to change this design so that when the ScrollBar of a ScrollPanel got scrolled it will always show the 3rd panel in GWT?

Tags: gwt

Ok, here is my current design, I have 3 panels inside a Grid & the Grid is inside a ScrollPanel. I want that when the ScrollBar of the ScrollPanel got scrolled it will always show the 3rd panel.

```
Grid myGrid=new Grid(1,3);
myGrid.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(0, 0, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_TOP);
myGrid.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(0, 1, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_TOP);
myGrid.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(0, 2, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_TOP);
myGrid.setWidget(0,0,panel1);
myGrid.setWidget(0,1,panel2);
myGrid.setWidget(0,2,panel3);
//normally the Panel 1 & 2 is much longer than panel3
final ScrollPanel myScrollPanel=new ScrollPanel();
myScrollPanel.add(myGrid);
myScrollPanel.addScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler(){

    @Override
    public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {

         myScrollPanel.ensureVisible(panel3);
    }

});
```

Ok, when i scroll the `scrollbar` of the `myScrollPanel` down to see the bottom gui of `panel2`, it always show the `panel3`, that is correct but i couldn't see the bottom gui of panel2 since the system forced to visible the panel3 all the time.

SO do you have any solution for this problem? 
maybe design differently?

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear to me. It should show 3rd panel always when scrolled or should show bottom of 2nd panel along with 3rd panel, Right?

Comment: " it should show bottom of 2nd panel along with 3rd panel", yes that's right

Answer (score 0):

I fixed.
 I put panel3 outside ScrollPanel,now the panel3 stand independently from scrollpanel